# PHP, uppercase a single character

Tags: php, string, char, ascii

Essentially, what I want to know is, will this:

```
echo chr(ord('a')-32);
```

Work for every a-z letter, on every possible PHP installation, every single time?

### Read here for a bit of background information

After searching for a while, I realised that most of the questions for changing string case in PHP only apply to entire words or sentences.

I have a case where I only need to upper 1 single character.

I though using functions like `strtoupper`, `ucfirst` and `ucwords` were overkill for single characters, seeing as they are designed to work with strings.

So after looking around php.net I found the functions `chr` and `ord` which convert chars to their ascii representation (and back).

After a little playing, I discovered I can convert a lower to an upper by doing

```
echo chr(ord('a')-32);
```

This simply offsets the character by 32 places in the ascii table. Which just happens to be the character's upper version.

The reason I'm posting this on stackoverflow, is because I want to know if there are any edge cases that could break this simple conversion.

Would changing the character set of the php script, or somethig like that affect the outcome?

Is this `$upper = chr(ord($lower)-$offset)` the standard way to upper a char in PHP? or is there another?

Comment: And the reason for reinvent the wheel is?

Comment: Nope, you should be safe in that range. To be sure you might grab a source distribution of php and check how strtoupper, ucfirst etc are implemented. However if you have no performance constraint, use the available methods. As there is no such thing as an overkill as 'a' is a string and not a character in PHP and strtoupper will exit after it anyway as there is nothing else to do. Again: 'a' is a string, not a char in PHP.

Comment: Apart from your solution being overkill (and maybe even slower, you might test that...) It will most probably only work with very small character sets. Most larger charactersets like utf-8 (which you should use anyways) arent that strict about their values. In short: Use strtoupper because secure, fast, proven.

Comment: Only safe with ASCII, not with UTF-8; but then strtoupper(), etc aren't safe with UTF-8 either; but there are equivalent mb_* functions for handling case-conversion with UTF-8 characters

Comment: You may also need to check if a character is already uppercase before uppercasing it by adding 32 to the ord value... the built-in strtoupper() function already does this for you

Comment: @Marcin I wasn't trying to re-invent the wheel. I was just curious if there was a faster way to upper case a single character. Turns out the PHP functions probably are the fastest way:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ASCII code doesn't change between PHP installations, because it is based on the ASCII table.

Quote from [www.asciitable.com](http://www.asciitable.com):

> ASCII stands for American Standard Code for Information Interchange. Computers can only understand numbers, so an ASCII code is the numerical representation of a character such as 'a' or '@' or an action of some sort. ASCII was developed a long time ago and now the non-printing characters are rarely used for their original purpose.

Quote from [PHP documentation on `chr()`](http://php.net/chr):

> Returns a one-character string containing the character specified by ascii.

In any case, I'd say it's more overkill to do it your way than do it with `strtoupper()`.

[`strtoupper()` is also faster.](http://glot.io/php/441557d6d5f18e38f1bacd398c93cf2d)

Comment: That's a really nice proof you have there. :)